# Get Active employees list according to month and year wise

Tags: mysql

I am having a condition, where I want to display Active employees, Inactive employees according to month and year wise.
For suppose if  4 employees are joined in January and if one employee is inactivated in Feb month.
Then for January month I should get the Active employees count as 3. I have written a query, whose results are not proper. Any help please

```
select COUNT(id) as count
from employee
WHERE (year(added_on) <= '2022' and MONTH(added_on) <= '01' and status=1)
   or (status = '0' and ((year(last_active_date) <= '2022') and
                         (month(last_active_date) <= '01')))

CREATE TABLE employee 
( 
  id int NOT NULL, 
  name varchar NOT NULL, 
  added_on timestamp NOT NULL, 
  last_active_Date date DEFAULT NULL, 
  status int NOT NULL
)ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

INSERT INTO employee (id, name, added_on, last_active_Date, status) 
  VALUES (1,'David','2022-01-02','',1),
         (2,'John','2022-01-03','2022-02-02',0),
         (3,'Carl','2022-01-03','',1), 
         (4,'Rose','2022-01-08','',1)
```

Results: Count 3 In above four results John is deactivated on february month, so Active employees in Janaury are three

Comment: could you please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar NOT NULL,
  `added_on` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `last_active_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int NOT NULL)ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



 INSERT INTO `employee` (`id`, `name`, `added_on`, `last_active_Date`, `status`) VALUES (1,'David','2022-01-02','',1),
(2,'John','2022-01-03','2022-02-02',0),
(3,'Carl','2022-01-03','',1),
(4,'Rose','2022-01-08','',1)


Results:
Count 3



In above four results John is deactivated on february month, so Active employees in Janaury are three.

Comment: Please don't comment with these stuff, but edit the question by using the information above while tagging the DBMS you're using.

Comment: I can not understand. John is deactivated in February, so in January you should have 4 employees and in February 3 employees

Comment: Sorry, @Sergey Total  Active count is 4 only for jan month